# Raytracing Reflection distortion

Tags: c++, c++11, raytracing

I've started coding a raytracer, but today I encounter a problem when dealing with reflection.

First, here is an image of the problem:

[image]

I only computed the object's reflected color (so no light effect is applied on the reflected object)
The problem is that distortion that I really don't understand.
I looked at the angle between my rayVector and the normalVector and it looks ok, the reflected vector also looks fine.

```
Vector Math::calcReflectedVector(const Vector &ray,
                                 const Vector &normal) const {
  double cosAngle;
  Vector copyNormal = normal;
  Vector copyView = ray;

  copyNormal.makeUnit();
  copyView.makeUnit();
  cosAngle = copyView.scale(copyNormal);
  return (-2.0 * cosAngle * normal + ray);
}
```

So for example when my ray is hitting the bottom of my sphere I have the following values:

cos: 1

ViewVector: [185.869,-2.44308,-26.3504]

NormalVector: [185.869,-2.44308,-26.3504]

ReflectedVector: [-185.869,2.44308,26.3504]

Bellow if the code that handles the reflection:

```
Color Rt::getReflectedColor(std::shared_ptr<SceneObj> obj, Camera camera,
                            Vector rayVec, double k, unsigned int pass) {
  if (pass > 10)
    return obj->getColor();
  if (obj->getReflectionIndex() == 0) {
    // apply effects
    return obj->getColor();
  }

  Color cuColor(obj->getColor());
  Color newColor(0);
  Math math;
  Vector view;
  Vector normal;
  Vector reflected;
  Position impact;
  std::pair<std::shared_ptr<SceneObj>, double> reflectedObj;

  normal = math.calcNormalVector(camera.pos, obj, rayVec, k, impact);
  view = Vector(impact.x, impact.y, impact.z) -
         Vector(camera.pos.x, camera.pos.y, camera.pos.z);
  reflected = math.calcReflectedVector(view, normal);
  reflectedObj = this->getClosestObj(reflected, Camera(impact));
  if (reflectedObj.second <= 0) {
    cuColor.mix(0x000000, obj->getReflectionIndex());
    return cuColor;
  }
  newColor = this->getReflectedColor(reflectedObj.first, Camera(impact),
                                     reflected, reflectedObj.second, pass + 1);
  // apply effects
  cuColor.mix(newColor, obj->getReflectionIndex());
  return newColor;
}
```

To calculate the normal and the reflected Vector:

```
Vector Math::calcReflectedVector(const Vector &ray,
                                 const Vector &normal) const {
  double cosAngle;
  Vector copyRay = ray;

  copyRay.makeUnit();
  cosAngle = copyRay.scale(normal);
  return (-2.0 * cosAngle * normal + copyRay);
}

Vector Math::calcNormalVector(Position pos, std::shared_ptr<SceneObj> obj,
                              Vector rayVec, double k, Position& impact) const {
  const Position &objPos = obj->getPosition();
  Vector normal;

  impact.x = pos.x + k * rayVec.x;
  impact.y = pos.y + k * rayVec.y;
  impact.z = pos.z + k * rayVec.z;
  obj->calcNormal(normal, impact);
  return normal;
}
```

[EDIT1]

I have a new image, i removed the plane only to keep the spheres:

[image]

As you can see there is blue and yellow on the border of the sphere.
Thanks to neam I colored the sphere applying the following formula:

```
  newColor.r = reflected.x * 127.0 + 127.0;
  newColor.g = reflected.y * 127.0 + 127.0;
  newColor.b = reflected.z * 127.0 + 127.0;
```

Bellow is the visual result:

[image]

Ask me if you need any information.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your `math.calcNormalVector(...)` function ?
Another little thing, in your `calcReflectedVector()` function you call a `scale` method, witch is wrong: "scaling" a vector lays a vector as result (not a scalar). The operation you're doing is called `dot product` and in order to avoid some confusion in the future I advise you to rename this method to the commonly used `dot` name.

Comment: What is the definition of the function `scale` as called here: `copyView.scale(copyNormal)`?

Comment: it's now renamed to .dot(

Comment: I have a feeling the issue might be where you are calculating surface normals. Could you provide the definition of `SceneObj::calcNormal` for spheres?

Comment: @JordanMelo The screenshot with the normals looks good, I also assume the code uses normals for lightning and reflect for the phong-like effect. Normals are strangely OK... So if it does not comes from normals/the reflect function, it may comes from... uhm... `Rt::getClosestObj`, but this is strange as shadows are looking quite OK too. But looking how weird the problem appear to be, it maayy comes from a mis-used call/value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many little things with the example you provided. This may -- or may not -- answer your question, but as I suppose you're doing a raytracer for learning purposes (either at school or in your free time) I'll give you some hints.

- you have two classes `Vector` and `Position`. It may well seems like it's a good idea, but why not seeing the position as the translation vector from the origin ? This would avoid some code duplication I think (except if you've done something like `using Position = Vector;`). You may also want to look at some libraries that does all the mathematical things for you (like `glm` could do). (and this way, you'll avoid some errors like naming your `dot` function `scale()`)
- you create a camera from the position (that is a *really* strange thing). Reflections doesn't involve any camera. In a typical raytracer, you have one camera `{position + direction + fov + ...}` and for each pixels of your image/reflections/refractions/..., you cast `rays` `{origin + direction}` (thus the name *raytracer*, which isn't *cameratracer*). The `Camera` class is usually tied to the concept of physical camera with things like focal, depth of field, aperture, chromatic aberration, ... whereas the ray is simply... a ray. (could be a ray from the plane where the output image is mapped to the first object, or a ray created from reflection, diffraction, scattering, ...).
- and for the final point, I think that your error *may* comes from the `Math::calcNormalVector(...)` function. For a sphere at a position P and for an intersection point I, the normal N is: `N = normalize(I - P);`.

**EDIT:** seems like your problem comes from the `Rt::getClosestObj`. Everything else is looking fine

There's ton a websites/blogs/educative content online about creating a simple raytracer, so for the first two points I let them teach you. Take a look at `glm`.
If don't figure out what is wrong with `calcNormalVector(...)` please post its code :)

Comment: You were right, the error came from getClosestObj

object->intersect(rayVec, this->camera); -> object->intersect(rayVec, camera);

Answer (score 3):

Did that works ?

I assume that your ray and normal vector are already normalized.

```
Vector Math::reflect(const Vector &ray, const Vector &normal) const
{
    return ray - 2.0 * Math::dot(normal, ray) * normal;
}
```

Moreover, I can't understand with your provided code this call :

```
this->getClosestObj(reflected, Camera(obj->getPosition()));
```

That should be something like that no ?

```
this->getClosestObj(reflected, Camera(impact));
```

Comment: I get the same result (almost).
Actually i king of know where the problem comes from, when I calculate my reflected Vector I will write it like this:


return rayNotNormalized - 2.0 * Math::dot(normal, rayNormalized) * normal;

Comment: No I still have the exact same problem (which I find strange because the modifications didn't affect the rendered image)

Comment: Okay, so the problem can come from this part of the code :

    math.calcNormalVector(camera.pos, obj, rayVec, k, impact);

Can you provide it ?

Comment: I added the function with comments, thanks a lot for the time you spend